# Not able to access angular directive's isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-controller, angular-broadcast

First Directive:

```
app.directive("myDirectiveOne", function($rootScope){
    return {
        templateUrl : "/custom-one-html.html",
        restrict: "AE", 
        replace:true,
        scope: {
            somedata: "=",
            flags: "=",
            functionone: "&"
        }
        ,controller: function($rootScope,$scope, $element) {
           $scope.firstFunction = function(){
                console.log("First function is getting called")
           }
$scope.$on('firstBroadcast',function(event, data){
                $rootScope.$broadcast('secondBroadcast', data)
            });

    }
```

Second Directive:

```
app.directive("myDirectiveTwo", function($rootScope){
    return {
        templateUrl : "/custom-two-html.html",
        restrict: "AE", 
        replace:true,
        scope: {
            data: "=",
            functiontwo: "&"
        }
        ,controller: function($rootScope,$scope, $element) {
           $scope.secondFunction = function(){
                console.log("Second function is getting called")
                $rootScope.$broadcast('firstBroadcast', {})
           }
$scope.$on('secondBroadcast',function(event, data){
                $scope.callSomeFunctionWithData(data);
            });
$scope.secondFunction();

    $scope.editFunction = function(x){
console.log("This is the edit function", x);
        }
```

Parent Controller:

```
$scope.parentFuntion = function(){
        console.log("No trouble in calling this function")
}
```

So, the problem is when I try calling a function from a `myDirectiveTwo` html template, the controller which is active is the parent controller and not the isolated one.

May be it has something to do with the broadcasts I am using?

Html Code:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in data">
    <h5>{{x.name}}</h5>
    <button ng-click="editFunction(x)">Edit</button>
</div>
```

The strange thing is I get data values and ng-repeat works fine on load. But, when I click on the button it doesnt do anything. And if I add the same function in the parent controller, it gets called.. :(
How do I make the isolated scope controller active again..?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong, could you please paste some HTML too or a JSFiddle replicating the issue? thanks

Comment: @Protozoid Added the html code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ng-repeat creates a child scope, therefore the `editFunction` ends up being on the parent scope.

> From docs
>
> ... Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given loop variable is set to the current collection item ...

[Docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#overview)

You can verify that this is the issue by getting your button element's scope and checking the $parent, as such `angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName("button")).scope()`

Although considered *code smell*, you can append $parent to your function call in order to access it, though keep in mind this now places a dependency on your HTML structure.

`<button ng-click="$parent.editFunction(x)">Edit</button>`

Comment: Okay.. Shouldn't there be a way to handle the parent scope in case of drectives? I mean does this mean I can't use ng-repeat in a directive and have the isolated scope controller active? There should be some workaround..

Comment: Well, it's generally considered bad practice to bind everything on scope because it turns into a *scope soup* ... instead you should try to use `controllerAs` syntax and `bindToController: true`in directives. [Docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) The issue was that I was using a deprecated method `replace:true`. This caused the unexpected scenarios.. As @Protozoid suggested, I looked at his link and found the issue.. 
To quote from the official documentation: 
`When the replace template has a directive at the root node that uses transclude: element, e.g. ngIf or ngRepeat, the DOM structure or scope inheritance can be incorrect. See the following issues:

Incorrect scope on replaced element: #9837
Different DOM between template and templateUrl: #10612`
I removed `replace:true` and its fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using a deprecated method `replace:true`. This caused the unexpected scenarios.. As @Protozoid suggested, I looked at his link and found the issue.. To quote from the official documentation:

`When the replace template has a directive at the root node that uses transclude: element, e.g. ngIf or ngRepeat, the DOM structure or scope inheritance can be incorrect. See the following issues: Incorrect scope on replaced element: #9837 Different DOM between template and templateUrl: #10612`

I  **removed `replace:true`** and its fine now :)

This is the link: 
[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#known-issues)